# What's the type of this Bonsai Ficus?

Tags: bonsai, ficus

I got a bonsai tree as a gift, all it says on the card is Bonsai Ficus, but after searching online to find the exact type of my tree I couldn't really get to a precise conclusion.

Could anyone identify it using the attached picture?
Thank you

[image: Bonsai Ficus]

Comment: Ficus maclellandii, Narrow-leaf Fig or Banana Leaf Ficus and a few other names too, see the link above for more details

Comment: I know the Narrow Leaf Fig as Ficus longifolia? Perhaps the name is region specific...

Comment: @Viv  same plant different name

Comment: Beautiful bonsai but my first impression says a sick plant.  Anemic green.  How long have you had this guy?  Did you create this bonsai or did you purchase it?  Can you get back to the guy you bought it from?  He'd know how and when to upgrade to a bit larger pot, are you root pruning?  What fertilizer have you used?

Comment: Whoa, a gift?  This is a nice gift!  Bonsai should come with hands on classes.  Giving a bonsai is like giving a puppy or kitten for a pet as a surprise?  From what I see he looks like he is pretty mature.  They need to be watered every single day.  All they have are a lot of stunted roots in a bit of soil.  That is a lot of photosynthetic growth to support.  I am thinking a bit of fertilizer (find out from the gift giver as much of this plant's history).  We need more pictures in different lights to see the health and advise, this plant is valuable!  Are you a gardener at all?